# Line wrap long `python -c` command to be < 80-chars

Tags: python, bash, command-line, continuous-integration, word-wrap

I have a Python two-liner to set an environment variable, which I run in bash:

```bash
ENV_VAR=$(python -c "from some_package import some_long_command; print(some_long_command())")
```

In bash, one can use `\` to line wrap long commands.  I am looking for an equivalent within `python -c`.  Is there some way to line wrap this command so it's not so long?

I would like it to fit within 80-char width.  Also, I don't want to make this a Python script, I prefer the `python -c` route.

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve the same effect with a shorter command, or how to add line breaks to the same command?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated the OP.  I am wondering if something like `\ ` exists here with `python -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use newlines instead of semicolons.

```bash
ENV_VAR=$(python -c "

from some_package import some_long_command
print(some_long_command())

")
```

I added a couple of extra newlines so the python code stands out.

Or, a here-doc (without extra whitespace to show it can get a bit cramped)

```bash
ENV_VAR=$(python3 <<'_END_PYTHON'
from some_package import some_long_command
print(some_long_command())
_END_PYTHON
)
```